# StructureMap pass arguments in constructor

Tags: structuremap

I have a constructor with some artuments

```
public class AppEngine:IAppEngine
{
    private IGreeter _greeter;
    private string _str;
    public AppEngine(IGreeter greeter,string str)
    {
        _greeter = greeter;
        _str = str;
    }
    public string Run()
    {
        return _greeter.Greeting()+":"+_str;
    }
}
```

Here from the factory i want to get instance

```
 var obj = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAppEngine>();
```

Here I want to pass Arguments that the constructor is accepting.
how could i do this.

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to specify the argument when you call ObjectFactory you can do it like this:

```
ObjectFactory.With("str").EqualTo(someValue).GetInstance<IAppEngine>();
```

If you need to do multiple arguments you can just chain these together. Note that you can also define a constructor value for all instances when inializing like this:

```
ForRequestedType<IAppEngine>().Use<AppEngine>().WithCtorArg("str").EqualTo(someValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Arguments Constructor    
Example(int id,String Name){    //Define    }//main method  
//Object Creation    
//Object  Creation for Default Constructor
Example e1=new Example();
//Object Creation for Arguments Constructor
Example e2=new Example(101,"kathik");}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question